# How to share Azure File Share data with the stakeholder within the organization?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, unc, sas-token, storage-file-share

I am trying to find an easy way to share some files (each of size 7GB or more) with the stakeholder within the organization. These large files are sitting on Azure file share. I tried to access UNC path with SAS token in Google Chrome. But it does not work.

```
https://XXXXXXX.file.core.windows.net/<FileShareName>/<FolderName>/<FolderName><SASToken>
```

I am getting "Resource Not Found.The specified resource does not exist" error. May I know if I am missing something here? Can't we share Azure File Share data just like Dropbox link or Google Drive link?

If there are any other easy ways to share the data, kindly let me know.

Answer (score 0):

**Two ways that came into my mind**:

1. Provide them Storage Account Access Key and they can use it to
   access File Share with rights on all folders and sub folders.
2. PowerShell connect script from Share to connect it and it will also
   persistent and save creds to user profile level and they will not
   be asked to put credential again and can access all the folders and
   files.